# Rails (3.2.16) Routing Error uninitialized constant InheritedResources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 2.3 app to 3.2 - in doing so, one of the plugins I used to depend on `ResourceController` is no longer available in Rails 3 (at least not a good port that I've found).  Thus, I've had to look to other options, each gem I've tried [rc_rails](https://github.com/ianwhite/resources_controller) and [rd_resource_controller](https://rubygems.org/gems/rd_resource_controller) as well as [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) has resulted in the same error:

`Routing Error uninitialized constant [ResourceController|InheritedResources]`.

They are most certainly in my gemlock and I've restarted the server in testing them.  It almost seems as if the gems did not install, for such an error to occur.

Here are my routes from `resources :projects`:

```
                projects GET      /projects(.:format)                      projects#index
                     POST     /projects(.:format)                      projects#create
         new_project GET      /projects/new(.:format)                  projects#new
        edit_project GET      /projects/:id/edit(.:format)             projects#edit
             project GET      /projects/:id(.:format)                  projects#show
                     PUT      /projects/:id(.:format)                  projects#update
                     DELETE   /projects/:id(.:format)                  projects#destroy
```

Here's the controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ResourceController::Base
#....
end

## OR

class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
## ....
end
```

Which all result in the uninitialized constant:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant InheritedResources
```

Here's the traceback for the inherited resource:

```
Started GET "/projects/3903/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 10:17:55 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant InheritedResources):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__542093477292722009__call__814078438384904527__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/debugger.rb:20:in `call'
  railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)
```

Here's the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock for inherited:

```
[myself]:myapp(upgrade/rails-3.2)$ cat Gemfile | grep inherited
gem 'inherited_resources'

[myself]:myapp(upgrade/rails-3.2)$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep inherited
    inherited_resources (1.4.1)
  inherited_resources
```

And the `bundle show inherited_resources`:

```
/Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@production/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.1
```

**Why on earth would these not be available?**

Comment: You've added it to your Gemfile? You've run bundle install? You've restarted your server?

Comment: I've posted the gemfile content above now. Yeah - I've restarted the server, completely.

Comment: can you go into rails console and type in InheritedResources without getting an error? If an error occurs, can you require it and try again?

Comment: No, I get `NameError: uninitialized constant InheritedResources`

Comment: Hmm!  Yes I can.  `require 'inherited_resources => true'  Then InheritedResources is available.  Do I need to require this in my application.rb file??

Comment: Something seems weird because you shouldn't need to manually require your gems, Bundler should take care of that for you. But without diving in deeper I'd say yes, require it but do it in the file where you need it i.e. your controller that uses it. This is a best practice that helps you determine which files have what dependencies.

Comment: If I require in the controller I get `cannot load such file -- inherted_resources`

Comment: Did you misspell that?

Comment: Oh whoops - yes I did.  `require 'inherited_resources'` in the controller results in the same error `uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base` (did a server restart too)

Comment: Interestingly though, I can get `InheritedResources`, just not `InheritedResources::Base`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46453/discussion-between-yekta-and-diego-greyrobot)